# Using C-G Theorem or CIF theorem evaluate this integral

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

There are multiple singularities in this region, do I just split this into a partial fraction and then evaluate using CIF?
$$I =\oint_{|z-3|=2} \frac{\exp(3z)\,dz}{z(z-2)(z-4)^2}.$$

Comment: No need for Cauchy integral formula. Plainly use **residue theorem** with classical formula $res(f=N/D,z_0)=N(z_0)/D'(z_0)$ for simple poles $z_0=0$ and $z_0=2$, the only ones that you have to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Among denominators roots $z=0$, $z=2$ and $z=4$ only $z=2$ and $z=4$ are in circle $|z-3|=2$, so with residue theorem
$$\oint_{|z-3|=2} \frac{e^{3z}}{z(z-2)(z-4)^2}\text{dz}=2\pi i\left(\text{Res}(f,2)+\text{Res}(f,4)\right)$$
and
$$\text{Res}(f,2)=(z-2)\frac{e^{3z}}{z(z-2)(z-4)^2}\Big|_{z=2}=\dfrac{e^6}{8}$$
Can you take it from here!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach is correct (but this evaluation can be in a more straightforward way).

The partial fraction decomposition gives
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-2)(z-4)^2}=\frac{A}{z}+\frac{B}{z-2}+\frac{C}{z-4}+\frac{D}{(z-4)^2}.$$
Since the poles inside $|z-3|=2$ are $2$ and $4$, then by the residue theorem
$$I=\oint_{|z-3|=2} f(z)\exp(3z)dz\\=2\pi i \left(
B\,\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{z-2},2\right)
+C\,\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{z-4},4\right)
+D\,\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{(z-4)^2},4\right)
\right).$$
After the decomposition, the residues are easy to evaluate because for $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$,
$$\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{(z-z_0)^m},z_0\right)=
e^{z_0}\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{e^{z-z_0}}{(z-z_0)^m},z_0\right)=e^{z_0}$$
(see also the [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)).